# App installation issues generated with ionic

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have certain issues with different phones with my ionic app.

I'm using sqlite for this app to store necessary data that my user needs. However, when I make changes to the application, whether logical or aesthetic, on some cell phones they still have bugs from previous versions, even when installing the new generated versions.
Has anyone ever experienced this? Is there any way to force cache clearing or something like that when installing the app?

PS: I'm new to ionic.

I have no idea what I can do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.